# Can PHP's getimagesizefromstring method be trusted for mime type

Tags: php, security

I just recently discovered the PHP method `getimagesizefromstring` and I am wondering if I can trust the mime type it returns me.

I used to use `finfo` in PHP to make sure of the real mime type, but is `getimagesizefromstring` trustable?

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php

Comment: No, it can be forged.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it most certainly can. It's entirely possible to embed PHP within an image file with a proper image mime type. http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017725/how-do-you-change-the-mime-type-of-a-file-from-the-terminal

Comment: Very interesting lectures, so there is absolutely no way at all to have the real mime type in PHP?

Comment: @YannChabot As the second link states, "The thing about MIME types is they're almost entirely fictional." What are you attempting to accomplish by reading the MIME type? Security? Image manipulation?

Comment: @ceejayoz it was security mostly... I tought at least finfo was the solution but it is not obviously

Comment: @YannChabot Best way to ensure security for uploaded files is uploading them to a server that doesn't execute code. Amazon S3 is a great choice for this.

Comment: You might want to look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @Thomas so I could just check if files contains the Hex signature to validate the file type ? And can a JPG (for example) contains its signature AND malicious code ?

Comment: @YannChabot Yes it's always possible, just don't make the files uploaded by users executable :) But magic numbers help detecting filetypes way more secure than mimetypes or extentions.