# How Can I Change Mime Type In the Metadata on File

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I want to change the "MIME Type" in the file:

```
└──╼ $exiftool realshort.mp4
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.10
File Name                       : realshort.mp4
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 98 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:01:19 23:53:01+00:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:01:19 23:53:01+00:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:01:19 23:53:01+00:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : MP4
File Type Extension             : mp4
MIME Type                       : video/mp4
Major Brand                     : MP4  Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]
Minor Version                   : 0.0.0
Compatible Brands               : isom, 3gp4
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 2014:11:05 13:51:33
Modify Date                     : 2014:11:05 13:51:33
Time Scale                      : 1000
Duration                        : 1.20 s
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 3
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 2014:11:05 13:51:33
Track Modify Date               : 2014:11:05 13:51:33
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 1.20 s
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 0.00%
Image Width                     : 320
Image Height                    : 240
Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
Op Color                        : 0 0 0
Compressor ID                   : avc1
Source Image Width              : 320
Source Image Height             : 240
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Compressor Name                 : 
Bit Depth                       : 24
Video Frame Rate                : 30.02
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 2014:11:05 13:51:33
Media Modify Date               : 2014:11:05 13:51:33
Media Time Scale                : 48000
Media Duration                  : 1.17 s
Handler Type                    : Audio Track
Handler Description             : SoundHandle
Balance                         : 0
Audio Format                    : mp4a
Audio Channels                  : 1
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
XMP Toolkit                     : Image::ExifTool 12.10
Media Data Size                 : 95268
Media Data Offset               : 4610
Image Size                      : 320x240
Megapixels                      : 0.077
Avg Bitrate                     : 636 kbps
Rotation                        : 0
```

If I do:
`exiftool -artist=ii realshort.mp4`
i can add artist tag with the value ii

But if I do: `exiftool -"mime type"=ii realshort.mp4` it won't work

I looked at: 
 https://libre-software.net/edit-metadata-exiftool/

And also here:
 [How do you change the MIME type of a file from the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017725/how-do-you-change-the-mime-type-of-a-file-from-the-terminal)

But I can't find any answer

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the MIME type.  It's not embedded data.  It's a tag derived from what the type of file is.

You could edit try editing the `.Exiftool_Config` file if you have one (see the [example config](https://exiftool.org/config.html)) to override the base definition, but that will only change what exiftool displays.  Another program or another computer will output MP4 as the MIME type.