# Swift - Create CSV file with text/csv MIME type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, csv

I'm using the following line in Swift to create a CSV file:
`filePathToCSV.write(to: url, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)`

Unfortunately, the file has a MIME type of **text/plain**. How can I change the MIME type to **text/csv**?
I've searched high and low for a solution, but haven't found one yet.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean, isn’t the MIME type deducted from the file extension?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it has the correct file extension of .csv, but MIME type of text/plain. If I re-save the file in any text editor, it changes the MIME type to text/csv, but I want the app to do it.

Comment: I think it is more of a configuration matter than coding problem, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/defining_file_and_data_types_for_your_app

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I believe that is for creating a custom Uniform Type Identifier? Comma Separated Values is not a custom type.

Comment: I know that but I still think you need to do something like this

Comment: I came across this SO post, with some intersting info on file MIME type that may be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017725/how-do-you-change-the-mime-type-of-a-file-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your input!

I received some help from the Apple Developer Forums:
https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/710757?page=1#721303022

Changing the line-break characters from **\n** to **\r\n** did the trick! The file command now shows the file's MIME type as **text\csv**.